# How can I destroy the data in session? PHP

Tags: php, forms, session

I am trying to destroy my session. When the user reorders, I want all the history to be deleted. When I click buy now, I still can see all my history purchase.

```
<?php
    session_start();
        $txtFile = "CheckoutPage.txt";
        $CheckOut = fopen("CheckoutPage.txt", "a");
        
        if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) { // post has been submitted
            
            if (is_writeable($txtFile)) { //checking if txt file is available
                $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
                $bananas = $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_POST['bananas'];
                $apples = $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_POST['apples'];
                $oranges = $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_POST['oranges'];
                $strawberries = $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_POST['strawberries'];

                fwrite($CheckOut, "Bananas:" . $bananas . "<br />" . "Apples:" . $apples . "<br />" . "Oranges:" . $oranges . "<br />" . "Strawberries:" . $strawberries . "<br />" . "\n");
                header("location:CheckoutPage.php");
                
            }
        }
    session_destroy();  
    session_unset();   
?>
```

Comment: I am very new to this... If there is anything wrong in my code, I am more than happy to change it to make it better.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your code is redirecting before hitting the session destroy. Try moving your session destroy code above the `header("location:CheckoutPage.php");`